# Packed struct size is 40 even though member sizes add to 36

Tags: c++, attributes, clang, structlayout

struct `K` is packed and the sum of it's class member sizes is 36. Each member has a `static_assert` checking this.

However, the size of `K` itself is 40, not 36. K isn't polymorphic etc.

Why is `K` not size 36?

Using Clang 16. I'm not aware of an easy way to visualize the struct, or I would have. If anyone can recommend a way that would be great.

```
template<class S>
struct P
{};

struct D : public P<D>
{
    uint64_t x_;
};

enum class E : uint8_t
{};

struct K
{
    D a_;          
    D b_;          
    uint64_t c_;   
    uint64_t d_;   
    uint16_t e_;   
    E f_;          
    E g_;          

    static_assert(sizeof(a_) == 8); // Passes
    static_assert(sizeof(b_) == 8); // Passes
    static_assert(sizeof(c_) == 8); // Passes
    static_assert(sizeof(d_) == 8); // Passes
    static_assert(sizeof(e_) == 2); // Passes
    static_assert(sizeof(f_) == 1); // Passes
    static_assert(sizeof(g_) == 1); // Passes

}__attribute__((packed));

static_assert(sizeof(K) == 36); // Fails, is 40 instead of 36

int main()
{
    K f;
}
```

Comment: Compilers can add padding between members to enforce data alignment rules.

Comment: @ScottHunter I thought the whole point of packed was to disable that?

Comment: This might be related to the ABI that is being targeted.  IIRC the itianium ABI has an issue with empty base classes.

Comment: This is not the same as the linked question. One of the answers there implies `packed` should allow what I am expecting.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you're correct. It's that base class..... I've just removed the parent and it works. Is there any way around this? I'm only using the empty parent for CRTP to share functions on the sub class members.

Comment: You might try using [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) to get some insight.

Comment: GCC gives the warning: "ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field 'D K::a_'"

Comment: There is a possibility that the compiler is throwing in a Virtual Function table, which may not qualify under the "packed" specification.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why would it do that?

Comment: The `static_assert` passed on my machine.  Homebrew clang version **16.0.6**, Target: **x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0**, Thread model: **posix**, InstalledDir: **/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin**

Comment: If you want to print out the internals of the struct (if you care), and the debugger is not the right view of the bytes, and looking at the compiler generated assembly isn't your thing, and iirc the code has a toe into UB land, you should be able to adapt this code I posted a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227655/4641116

Comment: _I'm not aware of an easy way to visualize the struct_ See: https://cppinsights.io/s/b99d45b3  But C++ Insights doesn't exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 2):

With warnings enabled for clang, the issue becomes obvious:

```
<source>:17:7: warning: not packing field 'a_' as it is non-POD
               for the purposes of layout [-Wpacked-non-pod]
   17 |     D a_;          
      |       ^
<source>:18:7: warning: not packing field 'b_' as it is non-POD
               for the purposes of layout [-Wpacked-non-pod]
   18 |     D b_;          
      |       ^
```

Neither GCC nor clang seem to document this behavior (see [GCC `packed` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#index-packed-type-attribute), [clang `packed` attribute](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#packed)), but it looks like using inheritance (from `P<D>`) disables the effect of `packed` for a member.
There is no inherent reason why `D` couldn't be packed in this case, it simply appears to be a general ban.

If any member isn't packed, to ensure proper alignment of all members, the `struct` requires additional padding. The alignment of `K` is `8`, as evidenced by:

```cpp
static_assert(alignof(K) == 8); // passes; alignment is normally 1 for packed types
```

Since `K` is aligned to 8 bytes, and the combined size of its members is 36, 4 padding bytes have to be added at the end to correctly align `K` to 8 bytes (by increasing its size to 40).

---

#### See Also

- [Trailing padding in C/C++ in nested structures - is it neccesary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74883158/5740428)
- [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119123/5740428)